# How to setup VLAN trunk on VMware Workstation guest?

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation, vlan

I'm running VMWare Workstation 10 on my Windows 8 home pc. I'm doing a test setup for what later needs to be done on a real server (with ESXi instead of Workstation).

The host has two physical NICs: a Broadcom and a Realtek. They are both 801.2q compatible. The Boardcom is connected to the internet. The Realtek is connected to a managed (physical) switch that is also 801.2q compatible.

The guest OS in Workstation is a Ubuntu server. Both NICs are bridged to provide connectivity for the guest OS. On the guest, the Realtek NIC is configured with two VLANs: 1 and 2. On the switch, port 1 is configured as trunk, port 2 and 3 as VLAN 1 untagged and the others as VLAN 2 untagged. The siwtch is an old (but still working) device: 3COM Baseline 2824 SFP Plus.

I want the connection between the Realtek NIC and the switch to be a real VLAN Trunk, but it seems my VLAN tags do no reach the Ubuntu server (Wiresharked it). How do I need to configure the host and guest OSes in order to have my VLAN trunk actually reach the guest?